# How do I link a badge in my tabs.html to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ionic-framework

I have my  inside of my index.html I also have inject it in all the right places in app.js and this is my code for my badge:

```
  <ion-tab title="Cart" icon-off="ion-ios-cart-outline" badge-style="badge-assertive" badge="{{tc.badgeNumber}}" icon-on="ion-ios-cart" href="#/tab/cart">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-cart"></ion-nav-view>
```

Then here's my code for my controller:

```
* Created by gabed on 3/3/16.
 */
(function(){
   'use strict';

  angular.module('tabModule', [])
    .controller('tabCtrl', tabCtrl);
   tabCtrl.$inject = ['cartService','$scope','$timeout'];
  function tabCtrl(cartService,$scope,$timeout) {
    var tc = this;
    tc.badgeNumber = 5;
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the controller in your app.js file.

```
  .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'TabsCtrl',
      templateUrl:  "templates/tabs.html"
  })
```

Comment: .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
      controller: 'tabCtrl as tc'
    })

Comment: Hmm, try binding your badge number to `$scope`.
`$scope.tc.badgeNumber`